# Calculating cumulative Markov Chain outcomes

Tags: probability, markov-chains, exponential-function, markov-process, simulation

I have a Markov process, with 2 possible states (1 or 0) and a transition matrix **P**.  State at time t=n is determined by x<sup>0</sup>***P**<sup>n</sup>.  As n goes to infinity, x<sup>n</sup> goes to the steady state vector, **q** = [q1 q2].

I am modeling a situation with strong positive autocorrelation, so **P** looks something like:

⎡ 0.99    0.01 ⎤ 
⎣ 0.005 0.995⎦ ,

where Pr(Success|previous Success) = Pr(S|S) = 0.99 and Pr(Success| previous Failure) = Pr(S|F) = 0.005.  Thus, this chain creates long strings of successes or failures.

I want to model Pr(Success) on a fine scale, say, every 3 seconds.  I have empirical evidence for Pr(at least 1 success in a 10 minute period).  So what I need is an equation relating Pr(at least 1 success in 10 minutes) to Pr(S|S) and Pr(S|F).

I was able to do this in a simulated setting, and it turns out that the values for **P** above produce a Pr(at least 1 success in 10 minutes) ~ 0.6.  I would like to hold Pr(S|S) constant and adjust Pr(S|F) (or **q**, since that has the same effect) to get the Pr(at least 1 success in 10 minutes) I need.

What equation will relate Pr(at least 1 success in 10 minutes) to Pr(S|S) and Pr(S|F)?  I used simulations and regression to get the line Pr(at least 1 success in 10 minutes) = 1-exp(k*q1(P(S|S)-1)), which is close, but it is not quite right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{Pr}$I'm not sure whether the time $t$ is measured in seconds or minutes.  I'll assume minutes; if it's seconds, please replace $10$ with $600$ everywhere below.

Here, as often, it's easiest to calculate "the probability of at least one" by calculating "the probability of none" and then taking the complement.

Let $X_t$ denote the state of the process at time $t$ and suppose for simplicity that we start at time $0$.  We want to calculate $\Pr(X_1, \dots, X_{10} = F)$.  This equals
$$\Pr(X_1, \dots, X_{10} = F \mid X_0 = F)\Pr(X_0 = F) +\Pr(X_1, \dots, X_{10} = F \mid X_0 = S)\Pr(X_0 = S),$$
which equals
$$\Pr(F \mid F)^{10} \Pr(X_0 = F) + \Pr(F \mid F)^9 \Pr(F\mid S) \Pr(X_ 0 = S).$$
Observing that $\Pr(S \mid F) = 1 - \Pr(F \mid F)$ will give you what you wanted.